# Listbox filter generating blank entries

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I've been struggling with a listbox filter for a bit. While i have it working for the most part, i keep getting a few extra "blank" results.

I load a database into Listboxes so the database can be closed after loading the data. `Me.Listbox1` is visible to the user. `Me.Listbox3` contains the base data which is there so it can always be reset.

The goal is that `Me.Listbox1` is filtered by the input in `Me.Textbox2`. Any matching result is fine, eg. putting in "G" can result in returning "graph" or "geothermal", as long as "g" is present in the word. Currently it should be checking column 4 for any matches.

It does al this, so no errors. But i also get a bunch of "Blank" entries. So when i start typing, or even when i exactly match one of the entries. It will show that entry on the top. But my listbox has lines below that which have results in the other columns.
The weird part is that the lines are clickable, but there is no data visible on the lines in the Listbox itself. But when "read" the `Me.Listbox.List(0,5)` etc. and put that into a Label Caption for example. It shows the data is there. I have no idea how it gets there and how to make it so that these entries do not end up in the filtered Listbox.

any ideas much appreciated !

```
If Me.TextBox2.Value = "" Then Exit Sub

filename = 4    
searchname = Me.TextBox2.Value
colcount = Me.ListBox3.ColumnCount - 1
Lcount = Me.ListBox3.ListCount - 1

Me.ListBox1.Clear
Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = colcount

n = 0
For i = 0 To Lcount
    comparename = Me.ListBox3.List(i, filename)
    If InStr(1, UCase(Trim(comparename)), UCase(Trim(searchname)), vbTextCompare) Then
        Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = colcount
              
        For c = 0 To colcount
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem
                Me.ListBox1.List(n, c) = Me.ListBox3.List(i, c)
        Next
        n = n + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Do you have any sample data for what is loaded into each of the listboxes? I believe your issue likely has nothing to do with your posted code, but involves how the listboxes are loaded with data.

Comment: Hi PeterT, thanks for getting back to me.. After bashing my head at it for another while i actually found the solution myself... the code is faulty but easy to miss.. the Me.Listbox1.AddItem should be above the "For" line of code. Now it generates a new line ever cylce of C. Considering it's looping for 9 columns to fill 1 complete row, it also added 8 other blank rows. How the ghosting data got in there in those blank rows is still a mystery to me, but their gone with changing the code 2 lines up :-).. thanks either way!